# how can to increment a variable according to the action of the user using PHP

Tags: php

how can I increment a variable according to the action of the user
more details : I have three links and I want when the user clicks on the first the variable must be incremented by 1 if he clicks on the second, variable increment by 2 and so on.

```
<?php  $var=30; ?>
    <a href="">first link</a>
    <a href="">second link</a>
    <a href="">third  link</a>
```

Comment: This can be achieved very easily using AJAX / JQuery . Now clear one point , after clicking the link and after the variable gets increased accordingly , will the page get refreshed and stay on the same page , or the user will be re-directed to the clicked page ?

Comment: There is a lot of detail missing from this specification. Oh and we dont work from specification, we help you fix code you have written

Comment: Like: Do we always start from 30 or is this a number related to a specific user. If specific user where is the count store? Etc Etc Etc

Comment: @PHPWeb After clicking the link and after the variable gets increased accordingly 
the user must redirect to another page

Comment: @RiggsFolly All users start with 30

Comment: After the user gets re-directed to another page , do you want to save the count value ? Otherwise it will be reset to 30 if you close the browser and re-open this page .

Comment: @PHPWeb Once the user is redirected to another page, I must save the count value not 30

Comment: In that case you need to use AJAX / JQuery

Comment: @PHPWeb I am not familiar with AJAX / JQuery can I do it with php ? or if you some  source about link in AJAX / JQuery can help me

Comment: Are the links will be external pages or internal pages to your website ?

Comment: @PHPWeb they will be external pages

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?php
$var = $_GET['var'];
$var = ($var)?$var:30;
?>

<a href="?var=<?=($var+1)?>">first</a>
<a href="?var=<?=($var+2)?>">second</a>
<a href="?var=<?=($var+3)?>">third</a>
```

edit: now it works as it should

Comment: This will reset the variable to 30 every time a link is clicked and will not give the exact clicked count .

Comment: @Jonas Bjork thanks for reply, I test your solution but the problem is that the incrementation always starts with 30 however we must start with the last value for example if we have 33 and we click by third we must have 36

Comment: If you close the browser and come back again , then it will again start from 30 .

Comment: Well the desc doesn't say anything about that and if so, it has to be done with cookies or another id

Comment: @JonasBjork Thank you your solution was very helpful